# jQuery Select the next element using a selector

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I know we can use .next() to find the next element of a given one. However, my situation forces me to use a SELECTOR.

I'm using [jQuery tools](http://jquerytools.org/) to build some [tooltips](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html) of a table, each "td" having two elements: a link and a tooltip div. My goal is to display the tooltip when the mouse hovers over the link. According to the HTML, it's placed right after the link so I need to select "the next element". The HTML looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" id="td1">Title</a>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <h1>Tooltip Title</h1>
    <p>A detailed descritpion</p>
  </div>
  </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" id="td2">Title</a>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <h1>Tooltip Title</h1>
    <p>A detailed descritpion</p>
  </div>
  </td> 
</tr>
<!-- more rows -->
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use .next() here since the tooltip() function only accepts a selector string as an argument:

```
$("#mytable img").tooltip({
    tip: '.tooltip',   // <-- This must be a string, so no next()
    position: 'center right',
    offset: [0, 15],
    delay: 0
});
```

Is there any way to achieve this, or do I have to restruct my HTML? Many thanks.

Comment: First, is there any reason not to show HTML??? Second, why not just add div class tooltip?

Comment: Could you perhaps use a function that returns the class name of .next()?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the div class tooltip, but that's why I want to select only the next one.

Comment: @hackNightly Returning the class name does not work since all tooltips have the class name "tooltip".

Comment: I've tried to return the whole selector by using $(this).next('.tooltip').selector but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("#mytable img").tooltip({
    tip: '#mytable img your_html_element',   // <-- This must be a string, so no next()
    position: 'center right',
    offset: [0, 15],
    delay: 0
});
```

Here `your_html_element` may be your div or span or any html element tag. you can give the name of that tag. This is same as how you are using img tag.

Comment: If I have many tooltips, all having a class "tooltip", this will only select the last one, but I don't want to use different names since I'd like to use a jQuery each loop to apply the tooltips.

Comment: Using class will select multiple elements. But your requirement is to select a single tooltip which is related to the hover image.

Comment: Yes. If I use different names, I'll have to write many tooltip() function, but if I use the same name, I can write a single function if I only select the next one.

Comment: Never mind, I think I can try to get the id of that element. Thanks.